# Import Graph From File in Tensorflow

Tags: python, facebook, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am attempting to import the protobuf published by Facebook from the DeepFovea project located here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebookresearch/DeepFovea/master/input_graph.pb

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

tf.GraphDef.FromString(tf.gfile.Open("./input_graph.pb",'rb').read())
```

I am receiving this error:

```
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

Should I be loading this protobuf in a different manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much Googling, it turns out you need to parse it like so:

```
from google.protobuf import text_format

with tf.gfile.GFile(graph_filename, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_str = f.read()
    text_format.Merge(graph_str, graph_def)
```

from code example here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/test_util_test.py#L84

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I just attempted to load using json_format as you indicated and received this new error: google.protobuf.json_format.ParseError: Failed to load JSON: No JSON object could be decoded.

Comment: Updated the answer. This method creates GraphDef without error, but let me know if it's not working with subsequent code and I will look further into it